# taylor series for two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

The theorem I have been given for this is $$f(x,y)=f(a+u,b+v)=f(a,b)+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{k!} \bigg(u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^kf(a,b)$$ where $u=x-a$ and $v=y-b$.

Find Taylor series for $f(x,y)=\sin x \sin y$ near origin up to the square terms.

I don't understand why this isn't just zero because $f(a,b)=f(0,0)=0$. The solution says it is $xy+...$

Comment: Since we want up to the square term, we have to go up to k = 2. When we take the mixed partial derivative, this ends up evaluating to 1, since cosine is 1 at 0, so the coefficient of (x-a)(y-b) ends up being 1.

Comment: but the whole sum is being multiplied by f(a,b) which is zero so that makes everything zero doesn't it. I really need to see a detailed explanation of how this is done.

Comment: I don't think that final f(a,b) is part of the formula.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed the partial derivative was of f without realizing why the f(a,b) was there. As GEdgar points out, the f(a,b) at the end is to indicate that partial is being taken of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is your misunderstanding.  When they wrote
$$
\bigg(u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^kf(a,b)
$$
they do not mean some operation applied to $f(a,b)$, which is $0$ in your case.  Instead they mean the derivative
$$
\bigg(u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^kf
$$
of $f$, evaluated at the point $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

For second order we get $f(a+u,b+v)=f(a,b)+\sum_{k=1}^2\frac{1}{k!}(u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial}{\partial y})^kf(a,b)$ and $f=\sin(x)\sin(y)$, so $$\partial_xf=\cos(x)\sin(y),\partial_yf=\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\partial_{xy}f=cos(x)\cos(y),\partial_{xx}f=\partial_{yy}f=-f$$
so at $(0,0):\partial_xf=\partial_yf=\partial_{xx}f=\partial_{yy}f=0$ and $\partial_{xy}f=1$, so we get $f(x,y)=xy+remainder$